# Reload classes during JVM runtime

Tags: java, class, jvm, classloader

I know there are a lot of questions about this topic. But they are mostly about preserving the state of classes and variables.

I want to make my application to get it's most recent version (all packaged in a single jar) and restart itself.

My application uses the main() function just as a starting point, so i just initialise one class and the whole application starts from there. So that got me thinking. I could stop the whole application in main(). Overwrite the old jar and then the JVM could, in theory, reload all classes except the class containing main() and the main would reinitialise everything and run it.

Is this too much hassle? Should i just use a bootstrap jar that only handles launching of said jar and downloading it's newest version.

Comment: A bootstrap shell script is likely to be the simplest.

Comment: Do u want to change jar at runtime ? and dont want to restart JVM ?

Comment: from my guess, you will at least need a) different jars for your main class and the reloadable classes b) use reflection only in your main class c) most likely a different ClassLoader for the reloadable jar

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using OSGi container. There are many lightweight, low overhead implementations out here like [Apache Felix](http://felix.apache.org/) or [Eclipse Equinox](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/). Many Java application servers are built on top of a OSGi kernel. 
It allows you to easily hot-swap whole jars (bundles) or even less granular units (features) at runtime with close to none effort.

Answer (score -3):

In Most commertial java applications that auto-update almost **always** always have a bootstrap application that controls the execution of the main app.  I'm sure there are lots of examples on this as well.